# Optimize a trigger excluding a particular user in PostgreSQL

Tags: performance, postgresql, triggers

I would like to improve the way a trigger in PostgreSQL is disabled when a particular user makes modifications.

E.g.: the trigger should be oblivious to changes made by an 'app' user and start on every modification from any other user.

I am currently using the following code:

```
IF (CURRENT_USER = 'app') THEN 
    RETURN NULL; 
END IF;
```

As in :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_flag() RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    IF (CURRENT_USER = 'app') THEN 
        RETURN NULL; 
    END IF;

    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        ...
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        ...
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        ...
    END IF;

    RETURN NULL;

END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER trigger_categories AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
    ON "categories"
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_flag();
```

Do you see room for improvement here? I thought about embedding the condition in the `CREATE TRIGGER` part, before the call to `update_flag()`, but I can't find out how. Would it make any difference?

Comment: Your PostgreSQL version?

Comment: did you try `for each row when current_user = 'app'`? (Available since 9.0)

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4.8

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, my version is too old. I guess it would be `when current_user <> 'app'` though.

Comment: Yes, of course it should be `<>`. Good time to think about an upgrade ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a_horse_with_no_name points out, on newer versions triggers can be made conditional on an expression using the `WHEN` clause to `CREATE TRIGGER`, as per the [`CREATE TRIGGER` documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html).

This is not available in 8.4, so you're already using the best available option, testing `current_user` inside the trigger and returning.

(Note that `current_user` is affected by `SECURITY DEFINER`. You might prefer to use `session_user` instead.)

In general, the performance impact of running a trigger that just exits immediately is fairly small, especially compared to the cost of index and table inserts/updates. I wouldn't worry too much; there are probably lower hanging performance fruit.

Comment: "there are probably lower hanging performance fruit": I love this one! This question was merely for the sake of perfectionism and documentation :)